# How to batch process (100s) of interpolations in QGIS or other open source software programs?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, interpolation, batch, contour

Is there an efficient way to run 100s of interpolations in QGIS or other open source software programs?

I have groundwater contamination data collected from monitoring wells at about **800** different sites.  I would like to interpolate a set of groundwater plume contours for each site.  I'd like to avoid running 800 separate interpolations.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is your data in the form of point shapefiles with each point having a *z* attribute? The other thing is, does the Contour plug-in work on your system? (It doesn't seem to work on some systems).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can do it with GRASS. Here are two helpful links:
[Interpolation with GRASS](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Interpolation#Reinterpolation_of_.22sparse.22_.28scattered_points_or_lines.29_maps),[GRASS Python Scripting Library](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library).

Comment: Right - simply write a small loop for the task.

Comment: @markusN, I'm planning to try this in a couple of weeks (first time QGIS user and new to programming).  I recently learned to write Do-Loops in Fortran, I expect that python would be similar.  Will I be able to modify the GRASS program and create the loop from the QGIS gui?  Or would I need to work directly in GRASS?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the ease of writing such Python scripts, it may be better to work directly in GRASS.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [SAGA CMD](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/saga-gis/wiki/Executing%20Modules%20with%20SAGA%20CMD), available both in Linux and Windows. You can work in Windows command line or in Linux Bash, and create loops for running the SAGA functions of data import and interpolation. The real cool thing with SAGA is that you can use beside usual interpolators, also various types of kriging, which will fit your well data. The visualization in SAGA is also quick.